# SSL issue with Docker - Let's Encrypt on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ssl, docker, nginx

I am trying to use lets encrypt with docker in order to put my website in https.
  I use docker with nginx proxy and nginx companion. I have set up everything correctly regarding documentation. My containers are running.

Now, i have an issue with lets encrypt here is the debug file provided :

```
{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "jack-world.com"
  },
  "status": "invalid",
  "expires": "2017-12-20T18:42:39Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "tls-sni-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/G_0PYv_VpnEEUbV1PUjpJZyOIeP6b0zPxXeAlyYXclE/2728472678",
      "token": "fXuUQ77koLDDTuAqEgeqQA1q_DHinF2wanQReSrgIdk"
    },
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/G_0PYv_VpnEEUbV1PUjpJZyOIeP6b0zPxXeAlyYXclE/2728472680",
      "token": "iab5h37N-Io6lzfi8-DKmccXsF8_Y5Ws_RYCcwzREBw"
    },
    {
      "type": "http-01",
      "status": "invalid",
      "error": {
        "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized",
        "detail": "The key authorization file from the server did not match this challenge [fnFwM8VZXXjIkSOci-z5_w4W2mN8oOIXA_d74gScLo0.K6eBCVMCFTPDy-GGls8jpd0O75tW9kFA9tsX7dEU_Zw] != [fnFwM8VZXXjIkSOci-z5_w4W2mN8oOIXA_d74gScLo0.4E3VCTFsySjUrqnCg0ooULx-3kbdPBygi0aWkvg5Gd8]",
        "status": 403
      },
      "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/G_0PYv_VpnEEUbV1PUjpJZyOIeP6b0zPxXeAlyYXclE/2728472682",
      "token": "fnFwM8VZXXjIkSOci-z5_w4W2mN8oOIXA_d74gScLo0",
      "keyAuthorization": "fnFwM8VZXXjIkSOci-z5_w4W2mN8oOIXA_d74gScLo0.K6eBCVMCFTPDy-GGls8jpd0O75tW9kFA9tsX7dEU_Zw",
      "validationRecord": [
        {
          "url": "http://jack-world.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/fnFwM8VZXXjIkSOci-z5_w4W2mN8oOIXA_d74gScLo0",
          "hostname": "jack-world.com",
          "port": "80",
          "addressesResolved": [
            "149.202.73.189",
            "2001:41d0:301::21"
          ],
          "addressUsed": "2001:41d0:301::21",
          "addressesTried": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "combinations": [
    [
      0
    ],
    [
      1
    ],
    [
      2
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is logs from companion :

```
argos@jackworld:~/JackProxy$ sudo docker exec jackproxy_nginx-proxy-companion_1 /app/force_renew -v --help
/etc/nginx/certs/jack-world.com /app
Creating/renewal jack-world.com certificates... (jack-world.com)
2017-12-13 19:03:34,715:INFO:simp_le:1538: Retrieving Let's Encrypt latest Terms of Service.
2017-12-13 19:03:36,629:INFO:simp_le:1455: Generating new certificate private key
2017-12-13 19:03:37,221:ERROR:simp_le:1421: CA marked some of the authorizations as invalid, which likely means it could not access http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/X. Did you set correct path in -d example.com:path or --default_root? Are all your domains accessible from the internet? Please check your domains' DNS entries, your host's network/firewall setup and your webserver config. If a domain's DNS entry has both A and AAAA fields set up, some CAs such as Let's Encrypt will perform the challenge validation over IPv6. If you haven't setup correct CAA fields or if your DNS provider does not support CAA, validation attempts after september 8, 2017 will fail.  Failing authorizations: https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/Xw790v5P8mgdjsh-A-_wvwcmAFRIu-6UxlT2l5I7JB8
Challenge validation has failed, see error log.

Debugging tips: -v improves output verbosity. Help is available under --help.
/app
```

I need some help to figure out why http-01 is invalid, and if this is the only issue.

Thanks by advance

Comment: nginx ignore .htaccess files

Comment: It does but wordpress does not. Nginx-proxy is a proxy. Wordpress is after the proxy.

Comment: Can you share your log from the companion and nginx proxy?

Comment: Just added the logs for renewal.

Comment: I have edited the lets encrypt log file. New error happened on http-01:

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Same situation trying to docker wordpress on https behind nginx proxy along with nginx companion....

Please post the solution. I have spent days trying this...

Comment: Hi, My problem was that i let the initial index.html from my provider OVH and did not activate ssl certificate on my domain (OVH Panel). Removing index.html made my DNS zone records to work and activating SSL at my providers' made it to the challenge,